# mapping analog value to pwm signal within condintional

Tags: arduino, pwm, arduino-c++

I'm trying to use a joystick to control the brightness of two LED's (which will eventually be replaced by stepper motors). The resting analog value for the joystick on the X axis is 504, with the minimum and maximum of course being 0 and 1023, respectively. My goal is to use a conditional to determine which LED to light, and how bright it should be. As the analog value approaches 1023, it should get brighter. as the analog value approaches 0, the other bulb should increase in brightness.

Here is the relevant code so far:

```
 if (xVal < 500) {
  analogWrite(7, map(xVal, 0, 500, 255, 0));
 }
 else if (xVal > 510) {
  analogWrite(6, map(xVal, 510, 1023, 0, 255));
 }
```

if the value is greater than 510, it behaves as wanted. The brightness steps up, until hitting 1023 where it reaches its maximum value.

For less than 500 however, the behavior doesn't work. It just does a maximum brightness when true, without adjusting the PWM. If I understand map functions right, shouldn't it be mapping an analog value of 0 to the maximum PWM value?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple and actually did not fall within a code issue. I'm an arduino noob and I realized pin 7 (for the less than condition) does not support PWM. I changed it to pin 5 and it began working. I also opted to modify the map function to make it more sensible.

```
  analogWrite(5, map(xVal, 500, 0, 0, 255));
 }
```

This is how I changed it. Using the map to invert the value, I thought it made more sense to have the first range flipped, rather than the PWM range.